# Create a CFG for $L = \{ a^ib^j \mid \lvert i - j \rvert \le 2 \} $

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar

I'm trying to find a CFG for the following language:

$L = \{ a^ib^j \mid \lvert i - j \rvert \le 2 \} $

What I thought about unsuccessfully is the following:

$S \rightarrow SASBS \mid SBSAS \mid \epsilon$

$A \rightarrow a \mid aa \mid aaa $

$B \rightarrow b \mid bb \mid bbb $

Which has the following problems:

***(1) It does not take into account words that do not have a's or b's***

***(2)
It is possible to add a greater number of a's or b's than the allowed distance, for example aaabaaab is a word generated by that CFG***

I've been thinking about it for a long time and it seems like a dead end because it seems that making CFG's is more of an art than anything else, I would greatly appreciate any help

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4124760/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/139805/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: @D.W. Oh sorry, my bad. I didn't know it, do I have to close this one?

Comment: At this point, given that answers have been posted on both sites, what's done is done, and you can leave it to the mods.  Now you know for the future.

Comment: @D.W. Okay, thanks for the notice :)

Comment: Cross posted https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/139805/create-a-cfg-for-l-aibj-mid-lvert-i-j-rvert-le-2

Comment: (the close reason is recorded as off-topic, and not as "something else..." for some reasons.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$S \to aSb + 1 + a + b + aa + bb$ should work.